# How to copy file from local directory in another drive to HDFS in Apache Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to Apache Hadoop and I'm trying to copy a simple text file from my local directory to HDFS on Hadoop, which is up and running. However, Hadoop is installed in D: while my file is in C:.

If I use the `-put` or `copyFromLocal` command in cmd with the file in the aforementioned drive, it doesn't allow me to do that. However, if I place the text file in the same D: drive, the file is correctly uploaded to Hadoop and can be seen on Hadoop localhost. The code that works with the file and Hadoop in the same drive is as follows:

```
hadoop fs -put /test.txt /user/testDirectory
```

If my file is in a separate drive, I get the error `'/test.txt': No such file or directory`. I've tried variations of `/C/pathOfFile/test.txt` but to no avail, so in short, I need to know how to access a local file in another directory, specifically with respect to the `-put` command. Any help for this probably amateurish question will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current cmd session is in D:\, then your command would look at the root of that drive

You could try prefixing the path

```
file:/C:/test.txt
```

Otherwise, `cd` to the path containing your file first, then just `-put test.txt`  or `-put .\test.txt`

Note: HDFS doesn't know about the difference between C and D unless you actually set fs.defaultFS to be something like `file:/D:/hdfs`

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume that you have installed Hadoop in a Virtual Machine (VM) on a Windows installation. Please provide more details on that if this assumption is incorrect. The issue is that your VM considers drive D: as the Local Directory, where -put and -copyFromLocal can see files at. C: is not visible to these commands currently.

You need to mount drive C: to your VM, in order to make its files available as local for Hadoop. There are guides out there depending on your VM. I advise care while at it, in order not to mishandle any Windows installation files.

Comment: No, it's not installed on a VM, both C: and D: drives are local directories. I haven't installed a VM.